# Jenkins Job automation

Tags: jenkins

There is two Jobs job A and Job B.

Jobs A is pipeline project and JOB B is freestyle project .There must be execution in  a way that JOB B has to run single in a day after the JOB A Build finish.

I configured the Job B  Build after other projects are built . Its working properly but it builds many times in a day as JOB  A builds many times.

I want to execute the JOB B once in day .

Answer (score 1):

Use the [BuildResultTrigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin). This can be used to configure job B to check every day at a certain time whether there is a new build of job A with a certain result. If there is, job B is started.

Comment: its looks JOB A is not buildable while I place it in JOB to monitor section.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: I have used that plugin and I can see the text box if I click on buildresultTriger section I can see the test box job monitor. I put the JOBA in that text box but it shows as a error this project is not buildable

Comment: And is this correct? Can you trigger Job A manually, or is it indeed unbuildable? The job might simply be disabled.

Comment: Have you got to the bottom of that ?
I see the same issue. In my case JobA is a groovy pipeline job.
JobB is regular/FreeStyle job
Can someone help. Thanks.

Comment: Also, do we have something like BuildResultRemoteTrigger plugin, to monitor the jobs on remote jenkins servers ? If we want to monitor remote jenkins jobs, how can we handle.